# How do I get more chocolate bars?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've ran out of chocolate bars and didn't realize I could enchant my giant spoon and knight's armor. Is there any way to get more reliably?

Answer (score 10):

According to [the Candy Box 2 wiki](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=chocolate_bar), you can only get 13 chocolate bars total:

- You can buy **1** at the shop.
- You get **1** for throwing 1630 candies on the ground
- You get **3** for answering the squirrel's questions
- You find **1** in the cave
- You find **3** beneath the tree, after finding the map (rocks) in the cave
- You find **4** in the hole

Without resorting to any sort of cheat/glitch, if you've used your 13 chocolate bars then you're out of luck.

---

However, there is currently a glitch involving the text-save/load feature that allows you to earn more:

- Go to *Save*, click *Get Current Game as Text* and copy the text
- Start the game over *(refresh the page)*, and get enough candies to get the *Save* feature again
- Paste the text into the bottom text box and click *Load*
- You can now re-earn the chocolate associated with the cave.  That means you'll find one more chocolate in the cave and, once you find the cave-rocks again, three more beneath the tree.

You can repeat this to gain as many chocolates as you want.

---

You could also edit your save file.

Follow the steps above to copy your game-state as text, then find the section with the text `number gameChocolateBarsCurrent=0`.  Change the 0 to whatever value you want, then load the game.

---

Finally, once you beat the game, you can [use the computer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137308/) to give yourself more chocolate.

Comment: The text-save/load glitch doesn't appear to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I found one in the caves, so they might be there randomly.

Comment: I also found one in the caves, but only one, which leads me to believe that it doesn't appear randomly.

Comment: @PietervanNiekerk I found 2 in the cave. So, yeah, I guess it's random.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some from the hidden treasure under the tree near the coast:

[image]

But you need to find strange stones in the cave first, which shows that part of the map to click on.
<sup>source: 5pike</sup>

Comment: I haven't been able to click there. How do I get to that hidden treasure?

Comment: -1 This is just an arbitrary 3 of the 10 chocolates you can earn.  They do not restock themselves - once you've found them, you can't find them again *(without resorting to a glitch, see my answer)*.  So, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you text save, reload, and go back to the cave entrance you can get the one you find in there and the ones in the trees again too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cheat yourself anything, you can save as text and then edit the text however you want, then load it. I don't recommend this if you want to finish the game legit though...