# Where do I get more chocolate bars from?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've already enchanted all of my gear except for the knights armor and the spoon (which I don't have yet, how do you get the spoon anyways?).

The only places I haven't really discovered yet are: right door of the desert fortress, the big empty room with a chest all the way up some plateau, the spikes room in the castle, hell and the developer. Unless theres a place somewhere hidden, I don't know where to get more chocolate bars.

Answer (score 0):

You get chocolate bars from the shop in the village.

Comment: My shop is completely empty

Comment: @Emfg - You can also get chocolate bars in the cave and other places on the map. It is a bit random but as of now there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Click around the base of the tree slightly below and to the left of The Lonely House.

Comment: Where's The Lonely House?

Comment: It's just above the starting village. It's the hut that has the locked candy box in it.

Comment: theres a pic that shows where to click in this thread; http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137169/how-do-i-get-more-chocolate-bars

Comment: Awesome, upgraded my spoon and my armor. Although the armor is kind of a waste if you're dependent on weapons instead of spells I think because it reduces damage done by 50% :/

Answer (score 0):

In the Hole there are 3 or 4 chocolate bars in one of the teasures. I belive it's the first treasure on the right.

Comment: Already got those I believe. Wasted them on making the special chocolate bars to grant me more power :/