# Defeated game, how do I add chocolate bars?

Tags: candy-box-2

Just defeated the game with some help of others, now I've unlocked the computer but everytime I try adding chocolate bars, it doesn't work. Adding 10 chocolate bar(s) doesn't work, neither does adding 10 pains au chocolat(s).

Comment: This game has the *weirdest* questions...

Answer (score 5):

Just type the following on the computer:

> add 10 chocolatebars
>
> add 10 painsauchocolat

Answer (score 1):

Just put the word together:

> add 10 chocolatebars

Answer (score -2):

You need to add 10 chocolate bars *and* 10 pains au chocolat.