# How many candies does it take to make the oven happy?

Tags: candy-box-2

In CandyBox2, I've had 5M+ candies and 180M+ lollipops on hand, and yet when I offer them to the oven, it says I don't have enough. How much do I need to make it happy ?

Answer (score 5):

The oven wants 100 candies and **1 chocolate bar** to become happy.

Comment: Dang! I wasted my chocolate bar on enchanting the spoon. Now I have to wait until I find another one. `:-/`

Comment: @Synetech: See [How do I get more chocolate bars?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137169/)

Comment: I already have more (I got four from the squirrel). In fact, I wasted another one on the oven and now have two pain au chocolat.

Comment: @Synetech they aren't wasted, the pain au chocolat's are used on the wishing well to give you a boost in 1 of three areas. I believe you should have a total of 5 of them after enchanting everything you can enchant with chocolate bars, assuming you found all bars.

Comment: @Nil, it was a waste at the time because the boosts are unlimited, and I still had enchantments I could use. *After* you enchant everything, then you can use the rest for boosts.